# NODE_ENV image promotion strategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, amazon-ecr

So I have a standard node app. I build it with Yarn, and push to different ECR repositories based on the environment I want to deploy to (stage, dev, prod). I also build with NODE_ENV set to developement/production depending on the image's destination.

This works fine, but the whole concept of image promotion means you should reuse images for each environment instead of having separate repositories, as far as I understand it.

The problem I am not understanding is how this is possible if I am building with two different NODE_ENV's. As far as I understand, when you build with NODE_ENV = development, various development modules get included.

What is the correct approach here?

Comment: I wouldn't build an image with `NODE_ENV=development`.  Use plain Node without Docker for normal development, and package the image without development-only dependencies for integration testing and deployment.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. I'm not sure which dev dependency was making me think that NODE_ENV needed to be set to development for integration testing, but i'm not sure one exists.